# Scan small areas at maximum resolution (up to 6400dpi)

Tags: scanning, twain, sane, pyinsane

Problem statement: I want to scan an image at maximum scanner resolution (6400 dpi on a Epson V850). This is partly possible from the Epson scanner "professional mode" in the software, provided that the scan area is limited to 21000 x 30000 pixels.

I'm ok with this limitation, I could simply scan small squares of the full area (at max resolution), then "stitch" them together afterwards.

I want to automate this, so I'm attempting to use pyinsane / SANE.

The issue is: the maximum resolution I can set is **1200**, as you can see from the properties reported by pyinsane

- dps_optical_xres=**6400** ([])
- dps_optical_yres=**6400** ([])
- resolution=300 ([50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 375, 400, 425, 450, 475, 500, 525, 550, 575, 600, 625, 650, 675, 700, 725, 750, 775, 800, 825, 850, 875, 900, 925, 950, 975, 1000, 1025, 1050, 1075, 1100, 1125, 1150, 1175, **1200**])
- xres=300 ([50, 1200, 1])
- yres=300 ([50, 1200, 1])
- optical_xres=6400 ([])
- optical_yres=6400 ([])

So the question is: how do I override this setting so I am able to scan small areas at **6400dpi**?

Again, using the EPSON Scan software I can scan at 6400dpi, provided the scanned area is small.

I know the limit exists for memory reasons, but it doesn't feel right that I can't adjust scan area and resolution, just like the Epson software allows to do.

The problems with using the Epson software is A) I can't automate the process, and B) I can't select an arbitrary scan area in terms of top-left to bottom-right coordinates.

*I'm surprised how there is no definite answer on this yet. Let's try to have one once and for all, for posterity!*

Answer (score 1):

First of all, beware Pyinsane2 is not maintained anymore. Its replacement is [Libinsane](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/libinsane.git). (I'm the author of both).

The maximum of `1200dpi` comes of the constraint on `xres` and `yres`: `xres=300 ([50, 1200, 1])` and `yres=300 ([50, 1200, 1])` (`resolution` is just an alias to those 2 options created by Pyinsane2).

Based on what you say, my guess is that you can get this constraint to go to higher values by setting first the scan area to a smaller one (see `tl-x`, `tl-y`, `br-x`, `br-y`). However after that, I don't think Pyinsane2 will reload the constraint on `resolution` correctly and so the max will remain 1200dpi (whereas Libinsane should reload it correctly).

By the way, just to be pedantic, if you have options like `dps_optical_xres` or `optical_xres`, you are not using Pyinsane2 on top of Sane (Linux), but Pyinsane2 on top of WIA2 (Windows).

Comment: Thanks @Jerome for this, I've since then tried out Libinsane. Yes you are right that was WIA2 on Windows.
I'm going to try your suggestion (setting a smaller area then see if the resolution constraint is reloaded in libinsane). If it works and I can stay well within the 21000 x 30000 limit it would be awesome!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like that setting a small scan area results in the resolution to change past 1200 (see full output of the "scan.py" example modified to add the various instructions.
To be fair there are a fair amount of warnings and errors which may or may not be responsible for this. The scanner does work, and scan.py using the acceptable resolution produce a correct image.
output of scan.py when I tried to change the resolution, and the xres/yres parameters:

https://justpaste.it/3l1iw

https://justpaste.it/6ozqk

Default parameters scan:
https://justpaste.it/8ejf6

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like a limitation from the WIA2 driver of your scanner. This wouldn't be the first time a manufacturer makes it possible to do more with their own application than with the generic TWAIN or WIA2 driver. There is however a fairly simple way to make sure of that: if you try scanning with the application "Windows Scan and Fax" (it uses WIA2 too AFAIK), can you reach a resolution of 6400dpi ?

Comment: Also, can you enable the info and debug logs in scan.py and send me the output please ? (just remove the `if lvl <= (...)` in the `ExampleLogger`)

Comment: Windows Scan and Fax doesn't reach 6400dpi either. I've also tried many other softwares (well, they all leverage either TWAIN / WIA2 anyway) with the same result. It looks like I can only go past 1200dpi with EPSON's software (which sadly has no command line interface). 
I don't have access to the scanner at the moment but will send these output as soon as I have!

Answer (score 0):

For Linux there is [ImageScan v3](https://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/imagescanv3_e.html) with command line option.

I didn't try ImageScan v3 but [scanimage (sane)](http://www.sane-project.org/man/scanimage.1.html) on Ubuntu. 3200 ppi worked without problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).